# Parse.Query unable to find objects when called within Parse.Cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm struggling to figure out why my queries will not work when called from Parse.Cloud triggers.

I want to define some logic after an object of particular class was saved (the class is 'Message' in my case).

I'm testing the following simple code in my `cloud/main.js`:

```
const conversationQuery = new Parse.Query('Conversation');
conversationQuery.get('myIdHere', { useMasterKey: true })
    .then(conversation => {
        console.log('### Conversation is', conversation);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('### Error is', err);
    });

Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Message', req => {
    const conversationQuery1 = new Parse.Query('Conversation');

    conversationQuery1.get('myIdHere', { useMasterKey: true })
    .then(conversation => {
        console.log('>>> Conversation is', conversation);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('>>> Error is', err);
    });
});
```

And when I start my instance of parse-server, the following is logged to the console:

```
### Conversation is { myObjectHere }
```

However, when I save any object of 'Message' class, I get an error:

```
>>> Error is { Error: Object not found. <stacktrace here>, message: 'Object not found.', code: 101 }
```

I'd expect it to log the very same object that was retreived when the server started but instead, it returns a '101 object not found' error.

I think I configured everything according to the documentation but there's a possibility I just missed something.

I'm using Parse Server 3.1.3 and Parse JS SDK 2.1.0

Comment: Yeah, should work, right?  You should turn on verbose logging and look carefully at the requests being made and you should be able to see the mistake.  If not, post them here (appropriately redacted of course) and I'll take a look.

Comment: How can I enable verbose logging? I looked at the logs in Parse Dashboard but they do not say more than 'object not found'.

Comment: @ArthurCinader, thanks, I can see now! I have a few instances of Parse Server running and somehow my `afterSave` trigger for `Conversation` class on `ParseServer` A, calls the query for class in `ParseServer` B.

I.e. the server A is under `/serverA/` URL and B under `/serverB/` but the trigger defined on server A calls `url=/serverB/classes/Conversation` in a GET request. Kinda weird.

Comment: By any chance did you reset or call Parse.initialize anywhere in your cloud code?

Comment: @flovilmart, no, I do not call `Parse.initialize` neither in `index.js` nor `cloud/main.js` files. Also, the cloud code is passed to only one Parse instance, the one of Server B does not have any cloud code. I will dig into this a bit more and open an appropriate ticket on GitHub. For now I run only one instance of Parse Server and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#logging it depends on how you start your parse server, but generally something like: `VERBOSE="1" parse-server`